# SSH and SFTP for ubuntu in oracle virtual box is not working

Tags: virtualbox

My ubuntu 16 is installed in Windows 7 Oracle virtual box but when I try to communicate with putty it says network error.Try to communicate with comand prompt it says timeout.please give your input.

[image]

```
Response:C:\Users\a591470>ping 10.0.2.225

Pinging 10.0.2.225 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 10.0.2.225:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 0, Lost = 3 (100% loss),
```

Comment: Does it have to be NAT? If not try using network bridge in the network settings of your VM. The difference is that NAT uses the host as it's gateway and communicates over it, while bridge allows the VM to get it's own ip address in your network.

Comment: Already in NAT but am getting the problem, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using NAT as networkcard in Virtualbox. It is impossible to reach the virtual box OS using NAT.

There are two solutions:

1. If you have two network cards like cable, wireless and both are connected to your LAN, then you can change the network adapter in VirtualBox to bridging mode an choose one of the network cards.
2. The second solution (I particulary use) is installing Haguichi on Ubuntu and Hamachi on Windows. Create a new Network and connect both to the same network and use the IPs given by this virtual network.

Comment: Guess the Hamachi thing can be useful if you are in a company network which limits the dhcp adresses.